# C# Parameterized Snowflake Query where value can be null not working as expected

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When using parameterized queries in C# in the WHERE statement how do you handle values that can be null?

Let's say we have a table:

```
ID|NAME|TITLE
1|'Bob'|"Boss'
2|'Bobbet'|NULL
```

Let's say that I have a simple query of

```
var commandText = "SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME=? AND TITLE=?";
```

I have two DBParameters that map to an object's properties like thus:

```
DbParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("1", DbType.String);
nameParam.Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Name)? DBNull.Value : input.Name;
DbParameter titleParam = new SqlParameter("2", DbType.String);
titleParam.Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Title)? DBNull.Value : input.Title;
```

When the query is executed for Bob like thus: The expected row returns.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME='Bob' AND TITLE='Boss';
```

When the query is executed for Bobbet like thus: The expected row doesn't return.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME='Bobbet' AND TITLE=NULL;
```

However if I alter the query to this: The expected row does return.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME='Bobbet' AND TITLE IS NULL;
```

How in code are you suppose to pass possible null concepts using a parameterized query? Or, do I have to use a conditional string builder to handle the possible null values when building the command text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of handling it is to use [IS NOT DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html)(predicate is part of SQL Standard) or [EQUAL_NULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null.html) function. Both are NULL-safe:

```
var commandText = "SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE 
                   FROM PEOPLE 
                   WHERE NAME IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ? 
                     AND TITLE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?";


var commandText = "SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE 
                   FROM PEOPLE 
                   WHERE EQUAL_NULL(NAME, ?) 
                     AND EQUAL_NULL(TITLE, ?)";
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b1b70ee35b2edbc3aac2ce6e55348917)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Performance wise is there a difference?

Comment: @aeatonDev They should have the same performance. It is a matter of taste(function vs predicate).